# How to handle OnBackKeyPress correctly?

Tags: windows-phone-7

To make it simple, I create a new app, which contains MainPage, and Page2.
MainPage has a button, which navigates to Page2. Also override MainPage.OnBackKeyPress:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Quit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            e.Cancel = true;
        else
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
```

Page2 is empty, except override OnNavigateFrom, to simulate a long time operation when back from Page2 to MainPage:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
```

Everything is ok, but when I am at Page2, and press Back key 3-4 times *very quickly*, then I see the message box popup twice.
I expect the message box not shown, or at least show and hide. Is there anything wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: I make some changes on my app: remove Page2.OnNavigateFrom(), then in MainPage add 60 buttons without event handler (just to make MainPage 'complex' and need some time to load). Then the issue can still reproduce. How can I avoid such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by very quickly...

The code looks OK (apart from the `Thread.Sleep` which is presumably to simulate a long operation on the UI thread).

I expect this is because while the UI thread is busy (or "sleeping") the back key presses are still registering and being sent to the app, and when the UI thread is available again it will process them one after the other.

This is a good example of why you should avoid blocking the UI thread.